# Emacs can't find latexmk

Tags: pdf, emacs, latex

I've been using org-mode in Emacs for a while now; specifically, I've installed emacs-mac with `brew install --cask emacs-mac` and then installed Doom Emacs.

A problem I've consistently had with my setup, however, is that when running `org-latex-export-to-pdf` or running latex code is an org-mode source code block, I always get the same error: `zsh:1: command not found: latexmk`. I've been trying to fix this forever; I installed and set up the `exec-path-from-shell` package, I gave Emacs full disk access, I gave Ruby full disk access (though emacs-mac doesn't seem to be run from a Ruby script anyway), and I've tried adding `/Library/TeX/texbin` to my exec-path and $PATH variable in emacs through my config multiple times. Nothing's been working, and I can't figure out why.

Is there anyone that could help me with this?

UPDATE:
I've simply hardcoded org-latex-pdf-process with the full path to pdflatex, which works fine. I'm still not sure why Emacs can't find it when all the paths are set, but whatever, it's working now I guess.

Comment: Open a shell in emacs, display the path, verify that this executable is actually present where you think it is.

Comment: @MarcWilson I've done this with `which latexmk`, and the path for `latexmk` is `/Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk`, and opening a shell in Emacs and displaying the path shows that it's on my path. In fact, I can even use the command in a shell in Emacs; it just doesn't work when running the command `org-latex-export-to-pdf`.

Comment: Then I would investigate exactly where you are setting your path, in which of `zsh` silly little multiple config files, and whether or not `emacs` org-mode is launching a login or a non-login shell.  The `zsh` man page will tell you when it is using which startup file.

Comment: The path is automatically set by homebrew in /etc/paths.d/ which is then read in /etc/zprofile, so that's not a concern; both interactive and non-interactive shells have access to these paths. In fact, running `(executable-find "latexmk")` returns the path to latexmk at /Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk, but running `(shell-command-to-string "latexmk")` will return an error.

Comment: The you need to look at what latexmk does - if it is a shell or prl process does it need other things on its path? - Can you run latexmk inside an Emacs shell (or better for debugging eshell)

Comment: @luardemin /etc/zprofile is only read if the shell is a login shell.  Also, depending on how your copy of `emacs` is getting invoked, I wouldn't count on it inheriting whatever you think your `zsh` config is.  Homebrew scribbles on /etc/paths.d?  Didn't know that myself.